# Flutter Error: Method not found: '_initRootBundle'

Tags: flutter, dart

**Flutter Run Error**
My environment is Ubuntu 22.04, and this error was generated when trying to compile into both a linux and web application.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
ERROR: lib/main.dart:49:34: Error: Method not found: '_initRootBundle'.
ERROR:   final AssetBundle rootBundle = _initRootBundle();
ERROR:                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

**lib/main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class DataSeries {
  final List<DataItem> dataModel;
  DataSeries({required this.dataModel});
  factory DataSeries.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['data'] as List;
    List<DataItem> dataList = list.map((dataModel) =>
    DataItem.fromJson(dataModel)).toList();
    return DataSeries(dataModel: dataList);
  }
}

class DataItem {
  final String title;
  DataItem({required this.title});
  factory DataItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return DataItem(title: json['title']);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'JSON Future Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(
        title: 'JSON Future Demo',
        key: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Future<String> _loadAssetData() async {
  final AssetBundle rootBundle = _initRootBundle();
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data2.json');
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<DataSeries> fetchData() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadAssetData();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    DataSeries dataSeries = DataSeries.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(dataSeries.dataModel[0].title);
    return dataSeries;
  }
  late Future<DataSeries> dataSeries;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataSeries = fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<DataSeries>(
          future: dataSeries,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.dataModel.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data!.dataModel[index].title),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Flutter version**

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 90c64ed42b (2 days ago) • 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500
Engine • revision 9aa7816315
Tools • Dart 2.19.5 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

I have tried searching [documentation pertaining to rootBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html) with no luck. Is there is an obvious syntax error that I am missing? How can I even begin to trace this problem with the feedback given to me from Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you actually don't need to do such thing as calling _initRootBundle.

Instead, the following import should do the trick.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```